# Avoiding if-statements with object oriented design, PHP

Tags: php, oop, if-statement

I'm basically creating a display-module for an ad-system I've created.

I'm trying to avoid the following construction, with repeated if-statements.

My gut feeling tells me there's a smarter way to do this, maybe with polymorphism?

```
<?php

class Ad { 
    public $adState = 'active'; 
} 

class AdWriter { 
    public function displayAd(Ad $ad, $viewmode = 'visitor') { 
        if ($viewmode =='visitor') { 
            if ($adState == 'active') {} 

            else if ($adState == 'paused') {} 

            else if ($adState == 'inactive') {} 

        } 

        else if ($viewmode = 'owner') { 
            if ($adState == 'active') {} 

            else if ($adState == 'paused') {} 

            else if ($adState == 'inactive') {} 
        } 

        else if ($viewmode == 'administrator') { 
            if ($adState == 'active') {} 

            else if ($adState == 'paused') {} 

            else if ($adState == 'inactive') {} 
        } 
    } 
}  

?>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apply the [Refactoring](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring) [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) and have a look at the [State Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state).

Comment: Does replacing conditional with polymorphism not just mean your putting your conditionals behind creating objects instead of calling methods etc

Answer (score 4):

You could create an [Factory (Pattern)](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Design-Patterns-in-PHP-Factory-Method-and-Abstract-Factory/), using an switch on `viewmode` and create an specific `Ad` implementing an [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) having an simple function 'display' for example.

Pseudo example:

```
class AdFactory { 

    public static function getAd($sType) {
        switch($sType) {
            case "AdOne":
                return new AdOne();
            case "AdTwo":
                return new AdTwo();
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Unknown ad!");
}

class AdOne implement AdInterface {
    public function display() {
        // All that AdOne does when displaying.
    }
}

interface AdInterface {
    public function display() { }
}

$oAd1 = AdFactory::getAd('typeOne');
$oAd1->display();

$oAd2 = AdFactory::getAd('typeTwo');
$oAd2->display();
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing $viewmode, pass an object that would encapsulate the logic for this viewmore and call its method that would do the work. This way you'll avoid the need for if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sneaking onto StackOverflow at work, so don't have time to write a detailed reply of all your possibilities.

But to 'tidy up' those ifs, you can do this:

```
switch $viewmode {
  case 'visitor':
    your_code_here;
    break;
  case 'owner':
    your_code_here;
    break;
  default:
    will_run_if_nothing_above_matches;
    break;
}
```

Comment: That didn't really eliminate anything though? I'm still stuck with repeatedly checking for the states.

Comment: Not if all states share an interface

Answer (score 0):

```
  switch($viewmode){
    case "visitor":
        switch($adstate){
            case "active": 
                //statement
                break;
            case "paused": 
            break;
            case "inactive": 
            break;
        }
        break;
    case "owner":
        break;
    case "administrator":
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In 8 chapter of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599098) you can find very detailed answer to your question.

In short: use [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) or Factories. (see answer of Wesley van Opdorp).

Also, avoid using string arguments as enumerable:
`$viewmode = 'visitor'`
with this argument, you will have to keep in memory all possible values of this argument. Or look into code of function to remember them. And these values are strings - good place for typos. Also, it will be very difficult to change values in feature, because all calls of this method will contain hardcoded strings.
Use class-constants:

```
class AdWriter { 
const view_mode_visitor = 1;
...
```

Also, `$adState` - wrong code, should be $ad->state. But using public fields it's bad practice too :)